# Sharing an application context between multiple wars of spring-ws services

Tags: java-8, weblogic12c, spring-jdbc, spring-ws

I am using spring-ws for SOAP based webservices development , As per my project design I have yo design multiple services , So I have packaged slimier services into WAR files , I have a total of 10 war files packaged in a single EAR file , Please find my EAR structure below.

```
MYServices.ear
|
|
|
-------APP-INF/lib
        |
        --------- All *.jar files includes DAO,Services,Exceptions
|
|
----------META-INF
            |
            --------application.xml
            --------weblogic-application.xml
            --------MANIFEST.MF
|
-------- service1.war
           |
            --------META-INF
                      |--------MANIFEST.MF (Class-Path: of all the jar's in APP-INF/lib in ear file)
            --------WEB-INF
                      |--------classes
                      |--------lib(empty)
                      |--------applicationContext-service1.xml
                      |--------serviceWs-servlet1.xml
                      |--------web.xml
                      |--------weblogic.xml


-------- service2.war
           |
            --------META-INF
                      |--------MANIFEST.MF (Class-Path: of all the jar's in APP-INF/lib in ear file)
            --------WEB-INF
                      |--------classes
                      |--------lib(empty)
                      |--------applicationContext-service2.xml
                      |--------serviceWs-servlet2.xml
                      |--------web.xml
                      |--------weblogic.xml
```

I have written all my DB Operations and Exception handling which is common for all the services in a separate jar file and place in the EAR(APP-INF/lib) location, I am trying to load my DB jar at the application context level so I have followed the below URL to load them in application context level.

https://spring.io/blog/2007/06/11/using-a-shared-parent-application-context-in-a-multi-war-spring-application/

My web.xml file for the services is followed.

```
<display-name>Services1</display-name>
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>WEB-INF/applicationContext-service1.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>locatorFactorySelector</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:beanRefContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>parentContextKey</param-name>
    <param-value>ear.context</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>serviceWs</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>transformWsdlLocations</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
```

My beanRefContext.xml is folllowed.

```
<bean id="ear.context" class="org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext">
    <constructor-arg>
        <list>
            <value>DataAccess-applicationContext.xml</value>
        </list>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

Please find my sample end point class below.

```
@Endpoint
@Scope("prototype")
public class SampleEndPoint {

    @Autowired
    SampleService sampleService;


    @PayloadRoot(namespace = "http://service.service.com/provider/sample/test/test/2018/05/", localPart = "sampleService")
    @ResponsePayload
    public SampleServiceResponse gpoReleaseBatch(@RequestPayload SampleService sampleService, MessageContext messageContext) {
        System.out.println(sampleService.sayHello("Hi Hello"));
        return null;

    }

}
```

I have similar structure for my all services , when I have deployed the ear into weblogic12C I am getting below Exception

```
Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'sampleService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'springshare.SampleService' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:581)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:91)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:367)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1340)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'springshare.SampleService' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1502)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1099)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1060)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:578)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:91)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
```

Note: Spring version is 5.0.2 and I have tried the context:component-scan for the common jar's in the individual applicationContext-services*.xml's

Comment: I see this is working with spring4.X versions and with Spring5.X this functionality discontinued.

Answer (score 0):

have you looked at " " parameter which might help your cause.. https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/wls/WLPRG/app_xml.htm#WLPRG483

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/soa/villena-coherence-web-sharing-2041803.html -- a good read on this topic.